# How change location arrow icon in google maps in swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

this is my code and I want to change location arrow icon (blue dot). how I can do it in swift code. I'm using google maps! I attached photo which is I want to do it.

[image]

```
func moveCamera(marker:GMSMarker){
     map.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: marker.position, zoom: 12, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
}

func placeMarkersInMap(){
    var marker:GMSMarker = GMSMarker()
    if(addressArray.count > 0){
        for add in addressArray{
            let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(add.longitud, add.latitude)
            marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
            marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
            marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker")
            marker.title = add.location
            marker.snippet = "\nTel. \(add.tel)"
            marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.44, 0.45)
            marker.map = map

        }
        moveCamera(marker)
    }

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        map.myLocationEnabled = true
        map.settings.myLocationButton = true

    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(// here will be your coords)

let london = GMSMarker(position: position)

london.title = "London"

london.icon = UIImage(named: "here will be your image name")

london.map = mapView;